# how to call more than one element of array

Tags: c, arrays

I am  using an array,i want to call 4 element from the array at the same time so i  can use them in an equation ,any one knows how.
example
int a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

I want 1234+15
how?

Comment: First of all you declared 10-element array and then passed only 8 integers. Secondly, I don't understand question and I doubt anyone does. Please edit it to explain it better.

Comment: a[0] + a[1] + a[2] +  a[3]

Comment: His English doesn't look good as mine. I think he wants to get 4 elements of the array and sum them.

Comment: i want to the first four elements of the array as if they were one number

Comment: @HebaFadhil 1000*a[0]+100*a[1]+10*a[2]+a[3]

Comment: No,I have declare a number of 300 digits as an array;now i want to use the first four digits

Comment: @HebaFadhil So where's the actual code?

Comment: I am generating RSA keys

Comment: now i want the the key e by using GCD

Comment: so i need no to call 4 digits together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using C#:

1234 = 1*1000 + 2*100 + 3*10 + 4*1

```
double result = 0;
int ex = 3; // Math.Pow(10,3) = 1000.00
for(int i = 0; i < 4 0; i++)
{
    result += a[i] * Math.Pow(10, ex);
    ex--;
}

result += 15;
```

Comment: thanks, it is a good idea can i use it in C++

Comment: yes, just google Math.Pow C++

Comment: now this program calculates GCD for the small number,but if i have more than 300 digits how can i do it , any ideas?

Comment: int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
 {
  int a[8]={4,6,3,3,2};
  int b[8]={7,1,1,6,2};
  double result = 0;
  double result1 = 0;
         double ex = 4;
  double e = 4,c;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{    result += a[i] * pow(10, ex);
    ex--;
}
cout<<result<<endl; 
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ result1 += b[i] * pow(10, e);
    e--;}cout<<result1;

 while (result!= result1) 
 { 
  while (result > result1)
 {c=result-result1; 
 result=c;}
     
      while (result1 > result)
   {c=result1-result;
   result1=c;}     
 }
     cout<<result<<endl<<result1;
     return 0;
 }

Comment: @HebaFadhil. If the answer above was correct, just mark it so. If you have another questions, start a new one and present the code in the question, it is easier to read and it is the way to do it. Code in comments is to difficult to read